# Android touch in predefined position

Tags: android

I have an android code which starts vibrating for a random amount of time when the user touch a screen. Now I want to change it a bit. I want to ask the user to touch a predefined position, for example in the middle of screen. what should I do that only in some special coordinates touching become effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a onTouchListener. The Listener gets a MotionEvent from which you can get th coordinates and check the position:

```
something.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // get coordinates from touch event
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        // check if the coordinates are in a specific area

        return true;
    }
});
```

To get the width and height you can use the following code:

```
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
width = d.getWidth();
height = d.getHeight();
```

Comment: But how should I check the coordinates in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
```

onTouch give you a MotionEvent, with this, you can simply do

```
event.getX();
event.getY();
```

for getting coordinates and do something with it (or not :))